# How to declare and use interface that exposes fluent API

Tags: go, interface

I would expect to following to work:

```
func New() Test {
    return test{}
}

type test struct{}

func (t test) X() test {
  return t
}

type Test interface {
    X() Test
}
```

But the compiler says:

```
Cannot use 'test{}' (type test) as the type Test Type does not implement 'Test'
  need the method: X() Test
  have the method: X() test
```

Which makes absolutely no sense. If I change the X() implementation to:

```
func (t test) X() Test {
   return t
}
```

It works. Is this just one more the wrong stuff they implemented it, or am I doing something wrong here?

Isn't the whole point of the interface impl to be decoupled with implementations?...

Comment: that's just a poor implementation as most of the language I guess...

Comment: There's some good things about go and some bad things. The language design definitely makes some different choices than other programming languages, and there's definitely a set of people who really don't like those choices. Some of them even know something about go and have experience in it.

Comment: "I would expect to following to work" Why? Which part of the language spec hints at this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Test` interface requires a method `X` that returns a `Test` (ie: an interface type). Your `test` struct has a method that returns a `test` (ie: a struct). A method that returns something that implements an interface is considered different in go than a method than returns an interface value.

Either change your `test.X` method to return a `Test`, or don't use an interface and use the struct directly if that's possible.